# Cygwin hangs/freezes when installing: won't finish downloading packages

Tags: windows, windows-7, installation, cygwin

[image: Cygwin installation dialog]

Just stays there. Restarting causes the same problem, and changing mirrors doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use an ftp mirror instead of a http one. This seems to resolve the problem.